# How to include collection field after Join in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some basic EF6 Models:

```cs
public class People
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Zoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ZooId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ZooId")]
    public Zoo Zoo { get; set; }
}

public class DbContext : DatabaseContext
{
    public DbSet<People> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Zoo> Zoos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to execute such query I get an empty Animals collection

```cs
var zoos = _ctx.Zoo
    .Join(_ctx.People, z => z.OwnerId, p => p.Id, (z, p) => new { Zoo = z, PeopleName = p.Name })
    .ToList();
```

How can I include the `Animals` field?

I have tried:

- the `.Include(z => z.Animals)` before `.Join(...)`
- the `.Include("Animals")` before `.Join(...)`
- the `.Include(z => z.Zoo.Animals)` after `.Join(...)`
- the `.Include("Zoo.Animals")` after `.Join(...)`

Comment: Tip: You don't because that will result in either a very inefficient query or lots of "+1" queries (both are bad). Instead, consider using `db.Entry( ... ).Collection( .. ).LoadAsync`.

Comment: You have an OwnerId in Zoo and it should obviously be related to People.Id. Why wouldn't you create a FK and use Include instead of Join on that?

Comment: Just after join, before calling `.ToList()`?

Comment: That's because in real code model `People` big, and only the `Name` of it is required

Comment: But you'll join the table everytime you execute your request anyways. And if you'll get only Zoo's without the owner through EF you wouldn't join. So what's the difference? What if you delete a person but your OwnerId will remain at Zoo's?

Comment: try to make your `public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals` and `public virtual Zoo Zoo { get; set; }` also it should be `var zoos = _ctx.Zoos.Include(z => z.Animals).ToList()` with `s`

Comment: You need only the include, if your collection is virtual, but it's not. So it's always included (Don't make it virtual to make the Include useful). if Animals is empty, there are probably no data in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var zoos = _ctx.Zoo
    .Join(_ctx.People, z => z.OwnerId, p => p.Id, (z, p) => new { Zoo = z, PeopleName = p.Name })
    .Select(n=> new {n.Zoo, n.PeopleName, Animals = n.Zoo.Animals})
    .ToList();
```

It's not exactly like `Include` but you can assign Animals to Zoo.Animals after query evaluation.